# index.php file gets downloaded after PHP reinstall

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, php, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM CE edition 6.4

I uninstalled the php5 from the server (Debian Squeeze) then reinstalled all the php5 with it's modules.

Restarted Apache (`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`).

Then after I try to login into my SugarCRM folder it justs downloads the `index.php` file, without getting me anywhere.

Anybody could shed some light upon this behavior?

Here's the link to my SugarCRM installation: [SugarCRMCE](http://clinicacastellana.dyndns.org/sugarcrm/index.php?action=index&module=Home&record=d923fabd-2f89-696d-563b-50a175a1a52a)

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

PHP still wasn't installed in the server, so I used:

```
aptitude install php5 module1 module2 …
```